# How to get videos and music in the same screen?

Tags: itunes

The last version of iTunes I liked was around 2010 when I had all my music and videos in the one menu list. Now if I want to change to videos from music I have to go to the dropdown tab (via mouse) at the top of the page. Is there an easier way?

iTunes 12.5.4 Mac

Comment: It would be helpful to know what version of iTunes you're referring to? And, is it on a Mac or PC?

Answer (score 1):

Although the concept of 'easier' is subjective, the simple answer is no. You can get the *identical* result (bringing up the movies) by going to the View menu > Media Kind > Movies.

The View menu also shows the associated keystroke commands to accomplish mouse-based actions. Cycling to the Movies window is <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>.

If keystrokes are 'easier' for you, then perhaps the answer is 'yes'.